# Can spfx domain-isolated webparts be deployed to teams

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-teams

The subject pretty much says it all. I created a domain isolated webpart that uses the GraphClientv3 to talk to graph.
it works fine when i run on a page in sharepoint. I added it to teams using the add to teams button in the new app catalog. but when i open it in teams it throws some error like ‘cannot get property (id) of undefined’.

Thought id ask here if it’s even supported before i go down the rabbit hole!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did a minimal web part setup to test it and got a similar result to you when adding as a Personal App. Below is a shot of the error. However  it worked when adding it as a Teams tab to a team. So maybe tabs are ok, but not personal apps.

[image]

Edit: Have discovered Teams tab isn't quite right either, the properties pane opens every time you navigate to the tab.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Indeed it does work fine as a teams tab!